# C++: Has Not Been Declared

Tags: c++

I have seen this type of error everywhere and, although I have looked at the answers, none seem to help.

I get the following error with the following piece of code:

error: 'A' has not been declared

B.h:

```
#include "A.h"
class B{
    public:
         static bool doX(A *a);
};
```

A.h:

```
include "B.h"
class A{};
```

To run off a checklist of things I've already tried:
- Names are spelled correctly
- A is in A.h
- There are no namespaces
- No templates
- No macros

I have other classes with can find A just fine. The only thing I can think of is that 'static' is causing a problem.

Comment: Does A.h include B.h? (it shouldn't)

Comment: Ah- Yes it seems it does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace the `include` with a forward declaration:

```
//B.h
class A;
class B{
    public:
         static bool doX(A *a);
};
```

Include files only when you have to.

Also, **use include guards**. This will prevent other nasty issues like re-definitions & such.

Answer (score 9):

If you have two headers including each other you end up with a circular dependency, and due to the way the preprocessor works it means one will be defined before the other.

To fix, I would avoid including A.h in B.h, and just forward declare instead:

```
class A;
class B{
    public:
         static bool doX(A *a);
};
```

You can then include A.h in B.cpp